# Ajax Requests in .Net 8

Tags: .net, ajax, .net-core, model-view-controller, pagination

I am converting a ASP.NET Visual Studio project to ASP.NET Core 8 MVC. I am having a problem with making Ajax call for pagination with X.PagedList. The original ASP.NET project is MVC and I code in Visual Studio 2022. The old project code has worked for years, but the move to .NET 8 is about done except for this Ajax pagination issue.

My applicable code that works in ASP.NET MVC is:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    var model = new ArticlesViewModel
    {
        f = ForumInfoBase,
        u = UserMasterInfo,
        ListArticles = articlesRepository.ListArticles(Forum, false)
                                         .ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize),
    };

    return PartialView("IndexPartial", model);
}
else
{
    var model = new ArticlesViewModel
    {
        f = ForumInfoBase,
        u = UserMasterInfo,
        ListArticles = articlesRepository.ListArticles(Forum, false)
                                         .ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize),
        ListCalendar5 = chb1,
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

The script that calls an Ajax response is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on("click", ".pager .ajaxify", function (evt) {
             evt.preventDefault();

             url = $(this).attr("href");

             // This function would get content from the server and insert it into the Pagination element
             $.ajax({
                 url: url, //this.href,
                 type: 'GET',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (Pagination) {
                     $('#Pagination').html(Pagination);
                     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                     googletag.pubads().refresh();
                 }
             });

             //This is where we update the address bar with the 'url' parameter
             window.history.pushState('object', 'New Title', url);
             //  historyedited = true;
             _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);

             // prevent the default redirect
             return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

In my .NET 8 project, I changed

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
```

to

```
if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
```

and use the same script to make the Ajax call as shown above.

The `X-PageList` paging works as expected but the call for Ajax does not work.

I think the problem may be in either the

```
if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
```

or something in the script to call the Ajax load that .NET 8 does not like.

Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

I have tried various changes based on a search of stackoverflow but have found nothing that works for this.

Looks to me like my problem is code I try to check if  IsAjaxRequest. It always comes up false, regardless of what I try with .Net 8, including some Extension settings I found for .NET Core.

Comment: Hi @Joe R, what do you mean for not working with ajax? Is there any error message?

Comment: Rena, there is no error message. The paging takes place but without Ajax rendering.